# How to create column marking latest date from grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, filtering

I am working with a data frame that looks like the following:

| ID 1 | Type | Name | Date | Marked | Updated_Marked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abs | 576 | 2009 | Last |  |
| 1 | sqr | 573 | 2020 |  |  |
| 1 | fun | 234 | 2020 |  |  |
| 1 | no | 556 | 2020 |  |  |
| 2 | abs | 364 | 2015 |  |  |
| 2 | sqr | 937 | 2019 |  |  |
| 2 | fun | 562 | 2020 | Last |  |
| 2 | ok | 794 | 2021 |  |  |
| 3 | abs | 846 | 2012 | Last |  |
| 3 | fun | 540 | 2015 |  |  |
| 3 | sqr | 276 | 2016 |  |  |
| 3 | no | 649 | 2017 |  |  |
| 4 | abs | 845 | 1999 |  |  |
| 4 | fun | 047 | 2012 |  |  |
| 4 | sqr | 176 | 2020 | Last |  |
| 4 | sqr | 959 | 2020 |  |  |

I am trying to write a program to correct and update the dataframe with a new `Updated_Marked` column that will correctly display "Last" given the following conditions:

Within each `ID 1` group, only look at rows with `Type == "abs" | Type == "sqr" | Type == fun`.  In each group, look at the latest `Date`. If "Last" is already marked next to latest date, do nothing. If "Last" is not correct, update new column placing "Last" in latest row. And if "Last" is not correct and multiple rows are tied for latest (same date values), then put "multiple" next to each.

EDIT: I have come across one more case - where a row is originally correctly marked as "Last" but because other rows within the group have the same year, it marks the other years as "multiple". In this case, I would like to assume the row is originally correct and thus make no updates. Changes have been reflected in initial dataframe and output.

The updated dataframe will look like the following:

```
+------+------+------+------+--------+----------------+
| ID 1 | Type | Name | Date | Marked | Updated_Marked |
+------+------+------+------+--------+----------------+
|    1 | abs  |  576 | 2009 | Last   |                |
|    1 | sqr  |  573 | 2020 |        | Multiple       |
|    1 | fun  |  234 | 2020 |        | Multiple       |
|    1 | no   |  556 | 2020 |        |                |
|    2 | abs  |  364 | 2015 |        |                |
|    2 | sqr  |  937 | 2019 |        |                |
|    2 | fun  |  562 | 2020 | Last   |                |
|    2 | ok   |  794 | 2021 |        |                |
|    3 | abs  |  846 | 2012 | Last   |                |
|    3 | fun  |  540 | 2015 |        |                |
|    3 | sqr  |  276 | 2016 |        | Last           |
|    3 | no   |  649 | 2017 |        |                |
|    4 | abs  |  845 | 1999 |        |                |
|    4 | fun  |  047 | 2012 |        |                |
|    4 | sqr  |  176 | 2020 |  Last  |                |
|    4 | sqr  |  959 | 2020 |        |                |
+------+------+------+------+--------+----------------+
```

EDIT2: after trying

```
msk1 = df['Type'].isin(['abs','sqr','fun'])
msk2 = df.groupby(['ID 1', msk1])['Date'].transform('max').eq(df['Date'])
msk3 = df['Marked'].ne('Last').groupby([df['ID 1'], msk1 & msk2]).cummin()
msks = msk1 & msk2 & msk3
v = df.loc[msks, 'ID 1']
df.loc[msks, 'Updated_Marked'] = v.map(v.value_counts().gt(1).map({True: 'Multiple', False: 'Last'}))
df = df.fillna('')
```

my dataframe looks like the following:

```
+------+------+------+------+--------+----------------+
| ID 1 | Type | Name | Date | Marked | Updated_Marked |
+------+------+------+------+--------+----------------+
|    1 | abs  |  576 | 2009 | Last   |                |
|    1 | sqr  |  573 | 2020 |        | Multiple       |
|    1 | fun  |  234 | 2020 |        | Multiple       |
|    1 | no   |  556 | 2020 |        |                |
|    2 | abs  |  364 | 2015 |        |                |
|    2 | sqr  |  937 | 2019 |        |                |
|    2 | fun  |  562 | 2020 | Last   |     Last       |
|    2 | ok   |  794 | 2021 |        |                |
|    3 | abs  |  846 | 2012 | Last   |                |
|    3 | fun  |  540 | 2015 |        |                |
|    3 | sqr  |  276 | 2016 |        | Last           |
|    3 | no   |  649 | 2017 |        |                |
|    4 | abs  |  845 | 1999 |        |                |
|    4 | fun  |  047 | 2012 |        |                |
|    4 | sqr  |  176 | 2020 |  Last  |     Multiple   |
|    4 | sqr  |  959 | 2020 |        |     Multiple   |
+------+------+------+------+--------+----------------+
```

Essentially, if a row is originally marked "Last" and it contains the latest date (even if there are others in the same date), I would like to leave the `Updated_Marked` column blank.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using 3 masks. The idea is to identify the rows that must be updated, using its Type, latest Date, and if it's marked "Last". Then for those rows, assign values in `Updated_Marked` column rows depending on the number of `ID 1`s it shares with other rows

```
msk1 = df['Type'].isin(['abs','sqr','fun'])
msk2 = df.groupby(['ID 1', msk1])['Date'].transform('max').eq(df['Date'])
msk3 = df['Marked'].ne('Last').groupby([df['ID 1'], msk1 & msk2]).cummin()
msks = msk1 & msk2 & msk3
v = df.loc[msks, 'ID 1']
df.loc[msks, 'Updated_Marked'] = v.map(v.value_counts().gt(1).map({True: 'Multiple', False: 'Last'}))
df = df.fillna('')
```

Output:

```
    ID 1 Type  Name  Date Marked Updated_Marked
0      1  abs   576  2009   Last               
1      1  sqr   573  2020              Multiple
2      1  fun   234  2020              Multiple
3      1   no   556  2020                      
4      2  abs   364  2015                      
5      2  sqr   937  2019                      
6      2  fun   562  2020   Last               
7      2   ok   794  2021                      
8      3  abs   846  2012   Last               
9      3  fun   540  2015                      
10     3  sqr   276  2016                  Last
11     3   no   649  2017                      
12     4  abs   845  1999                      
13     4  fun    47  2012                      
14     4  sqr   176  2020   Last               
15     4  sqr   959  2020
```

Comment: Hello, this works well except in one new case that I've diagnosed: where a row is originally correctly marked as "Last" but because other rows within the group have the same year, it marks the other years as "multiple". In this case, I would like to assume the row is correct and thus make no updates.

Comment: @toastienf could you update your question with an input and output to highlight the issue? I’ll update the answer using it.

Comment: yes, I will do that right now. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply and the edit. I tried it and unfortunately am still experiencing the same issue. I have edited the post with output to reflect this.

Comment: @toastienf that's strange; it works for me. Maybe restart your kernel and rerun?

Comment: thanks! I restarted the kernel and unfortunately it still has several groups with multiple rows in the same latest `Date` still marked as "Last". For now I can use this, though. I will try to clear up the `Updated_Marked` column and ask a new question if I'm still having issues since I don't want to convolute this post too much.